# DNS over UDP example query

Tags: c, dns, udp

I often find myself in need to test if an internet connection is online or not. In particular, sometimes it happens (on very, very peculiar connections) that UDP is disabled. Now, I figured that one of the most simple ways to test if UDP is available to my connection is through a DNS query.

Now, using some function like `getaddrinfo` abstracts away UDP from the query, so that (as far as my understanding goes) if UDP is not available, TCP will be used instead. Now, since I need to test for UDP connections, I will need to forge the UDP packet with the query myself. Moreover, I would like to make the query to a public DNS server (like 8.8.8.8), so that I am certain that the UDP connection is available to talk to external hosts.

So I am wondering: what is the most simple DNS query that I can send via an UDP packet? Could you show me an example that just asks for the ip, say, of google.com to a DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but the simplest query would be something like `SOA` for `.` (i.e. the start of authority for the root zone), like this:

```
$ dig SOA . @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> SOA . @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46366
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.              IN  SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
.           4350    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2015102500 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 36 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 25 21:07:19 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

If you are asking what that looks like as a UDP packet, simply capture it with tcpdump. However, such trivial DNS packets are relatively easy to construct in C - see [RFC1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt). You may want to use a pre-existing library like [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) or [adns](http://www.gnu.org/software/adns/).

Note that as far as I remember, whether your resolver library falls back to TCP is implementation dependent. IIRC glibc on linux does not fall back to TCP, and libresolv on OpenBSD only does if `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `options tcp`. When using `libresolv` programatically you merely need to [ensure `RES_USEVC` is clear](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch15_02.htm).

If you are looking for example code, *'Stevens' TCP/IP illustrated'* is the canonical answer.